# Issue After Installing New Pods Into Project

Tags: cocoapods, alamofire

I'm new to coding, so anything is appreciated! I created a project and realized I needed to install Alamofire into my project, instead of AFNetworking. Once I did this and uninstalled AFNetworking, I got dozens of errors. I read online that using the old Swift version and having a newer form of Alamofire can cause issues. So I needed to convert my code to Swift 3 by clicking edit, convert to latex swift context, etc. Once I did this, I got more issues as well. I have no clue what's all of a sudden wrong and how to fix this. What do I do? Attached are a list of errors. Thanks!

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update **your** code to Swift3. Not the Framework's code. Also you can check Framework's branches to find out if there is a Swift branch matching your version:

Alamofire for Swift3 = `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'`

Alamofire for Swift2 = `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.5'`